# How to use asp:Table in asp:ListView LayoutTemplate ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I get the following exception message when I call the DataBind() method of the ListView

`'Table' cannot have children of type 'ListViewDataItem'.`

Here's my markup

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="t" runat="server" CssClass="contentframework">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>1</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>2</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>

            <asp:TableRow ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />

        </asp:Table>


    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell><%# Eval("1") %></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><%# Eval("2") %></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <h2>No Records!</h2>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: any particular reason on using the asp control `asp:Table` over good old html `table`?

Comment: Any reason why I shouldn't?

Comment: @banging: 'Table' cannot have children of type 'ListViewDatatItem' comes to mind.

Comment: @banging: is this an academic question? `asp:Table` gets rendered as html `table` and I dont see any reason why you stick to `asp:Table` @Joel: we had some sort of edit war going on :)

Comment: @naveen this isn't an academic question.

Comment: @Joel it seems it has been done before i just can't find a complete working example..

Comment: @banging: if this is not so i dont see any point / advantage in you using `asp:Table`. `asp:WebForms` model gives you very powerful datapresentation controls but using something as flexible as ListView (allowing you your own markup) with asp:Table is blasphemy. and on an un-related side-note, you could write the above code much easily using a GridView

Comment: @naveen for consistency of rendering. I'm using asp:Table everywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

Asp.net serverside controls have some [hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310919%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). so it will not allow `ListViewDataItem` as the child element of `asp:Table` element.

So, Better you try simple html table tags instead of serverside tags, as:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="t" class="contentframework">
            <thead>
                <th>
                    1
                </th>
                <th>
                    2
                </th>
            </thead>
           <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("1") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("2") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <h2>
            No Records!</h2>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

As a reference for List view  you can look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET-3-5) article.

**More details:**

Your are facing the exception because, The [ListViewDataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewdataitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class represents an individual data item in a ListView control(Which is DataBoundControl), so it can not be the child control of Table class directly but it can be child of HTML table obviously when you directly embed it into html tags (as shown in code above).

Comment: This answer could be better if it went more in-depth on how asp.net hierarchy works and why this excludes ListViewDataItem being a child of asp:Table. Sourced, preferably.

Comment: @called2voyage thanks for your suggestions, I have edited my answer and tried to explain that part also, hope that might be a help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:Table ID="t" runat="server" CssClass="contentframework">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>1</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>2</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>

        <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />

    </asp:Table>


</LayoutTemplate>
```

This should allow the list item to populate as an actual row.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I neglected to mention that I had tried that before and I get the following >> `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRowCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow'. 'asp:PlaceHolder' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder'.`

Comment: Yah, that makes sense. You shouldn't be mixing these. If you have a need to do anything like this, you should be using either an html table or a Repeater.

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest an asp:tableCell in the asp:TableRow and then the placeholder should work in the tablecell

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server">
    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemplaceholder" />
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>`
```

Comment: That produces a single row/cell table.